# Ayuda / Consejos para manipular fechas y formatos leyendo las mismas con un BufferedReader

Tags: java, date

Hice un programa que lee un archivo txt línea por línea con un BufferedReader. Si en la línea que lee encuentra el String "Fecha de Emisión", toma desde el caracter 83 al 93 de esa línea (que sería la fecha propiamente dicha) y la guarda en una variable String para luego aplicarle un formato particular.

**Problema a solucionar:**

La "Fecha de Emisión" viene con formato (EJEMPLO) ---> 6/12/2018

Necesito que el formato sea SIEMPRE de tipo 06/12/2018 (osea DD/MM/AAAA).

Lo que se me ocurrió hacer fue esto:

```
   while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                    if(strLine.contains("Fecha de Emision: ")){
                        String date = strLine.substring(83,93);
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
                        String dateString = format.format(new Date(date));
                        String newDate = strLine.replace(date, dateString);
                        writer.write(newDate+"\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        writer.write(strLine+"\n");
                    }
                }
```

que sí funciona en el caso de que la fecha venga en el formato 6/12/2018, pero me agrega un 0 (cero) medio aleatorio en caso de que la fecha venga bien, osea en formato 06/12/2018, lo que estaría mal para la funcionalidad que necesito.

No se me ocurre como puedo llegar a validar como viene el formato para luego decirle al programa, si el formato es así: 6/12/2018 cambialo y si es así 06/12/2018 dejalo como está.

¿ Ayuda, consejos ? Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podés hacer es un `String#split()` con la barra de fecha `(/)`.
Y ahí:

1. Verificar ue te de un array de logitud 3 (dia, mes, y año).
2. Convertir a `int` los tres valores del array sin que tire un `NumberFormatException` (hacerlo adentro de un `try - catch`).
3. Y volver a armar el String concatenando los 3 valores, teniendo en cuenta que si el día o el mes son menores a 9 le tenes que agregar un '0' adelante del valor respectivo (cuando rearmas el string).

Nota: No lo puse, pero también podés validar los máximos y minimos para cada campo, principalmente dia y mes.

Comment: voy a probar ... gracias por el consejo hermano :)

Comment: ! Efectivamente me tira un NumberFormatException ... como hago para que no salga esto ?? Lo estoy parseando así:

Comment: String date = strLine.substring(83,93);
                        String[] parts = date.split("/");
                        try{
                            int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                            writer.write("day " + day);
                        }

Comment: Debuguiá lo que tenes en parts[0], parts[1] , parts[2], si no es un número tira esa excepción.

Comment: Solucionado, tenía un espacio adelante del número!! Te acepto la respuesta porque me ayudo mucho, gracias de nuevo Juan :)